# Run a python script from Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension, and I want the extension to pass data to a Python script which would do some magic and then return a response to the extension.

I want to make it as user-friendly as possible; thus I'd prefer not to have the user manually run the python script.

How can I make the extension run the script?

(Please note that I'm looking to build an extension - thus I can't move everything to be Python-only)

Comment: Where do you want the "magic" to happen? A server somewhere?

Comment: No, I want it to run on the user's machine.
I'm trying to avoid using a server (otherwise, I'd have just made the server listen to incoming data and then return the responses).

Comment: Why do you want to run a python script? Can't you implement this in JS?Basically, you can't do what you want unless you get the user to launch a process (and even then it will be hard and very annoying to set up). And I'm guessing you probably want something even more than just a standalone pure python script. Let us know what you want to achieve, rather than how.

Comment: I want to pass data to a ML model I trained, and pass the response to the chrome extension and display it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to my knowledge to do that. A chrome extension is basically a JavaScript domain. To run a python script would mean the "client" should have a python interpreter and run process in his/her computer.

Comment: Maybe there's a way I can "compile" python to JS or something like that?
And with a virtual environment take care of the dependencies?

Comment: @HaMankal, maybe you can try with something like [Brython](http://www.brython.info/). However I think if that works then maybe it's easier to write the code in javascript directly.

Comment: @Sanxofon the person wants to be able to run a whole lot of dependencies, some of which are absolutely certain to be in C. The only reasonable option for this is the link in the closure message.